# SQL Server : update from one table with Select and Join two another table

Tags: sql-server, select, join, sql-update

I have two tables:

**Teams**

```
Id  Name
1   Manchester
2   Arsenal
3   Inter
4   Milan
```

**Games**

```
GameId  FirstTeamId GoalsFirstTeam  GoalsSecondTeam SecondTeamId
1            1            0                 0             2
2            3            2                 3             4
3            1            1                 1             3
```

I want to update into `GameResult` with a select and join from two tables `Games` and `Teams` like this:

```
GameId  FirstTeam   GoalsFT GoalsST SecondTeam
1       Manchester    0        0     Arsenal
2       Inter         2        3     Milan
3       Manchester    1        1     Inter
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE GameResult
SET    GameId = (SELECT GameId
                 FROM   Games),
       FirstTeam = (SELECT t1.Name AS FirstTeam
                    FROM   Games AS g
                           INNER JOIN Teams t1
                                   ON g.FirstTeamId = t1.Id),
       GoalsFT = (SELECT GoalsFirstTeam
                  FROM   Games),
       GoalsST = (SELECT GoalsSecondTeam
                  FROM   Games),
       SecondTeam = (SELECT t2.Name AS SecondTeam
                     FROM   Games AS g
                            INNER JOIN Teams t2
                                    ON g.SecondTeamId = t2.Id)
```

...but it didn't work.

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: do you really need GameResult  table ?

Comment: Yes, because with GameResult easier to work, processing results

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE GameResult
SET GameId = G.GameId,
       FirstTeam = T1.Name,
       GoalsFT = G.GoalsFirstTeam,
       GoalsST = G.GoalsSecondTeam,
       SecondTeam = T2.Name 
 FROM Games G INNER JOIN Teams T1 ON G.FirstTeamID=T1.ID
        INNER JOIN Teams T2 ON G.SecondTeamId=T2.ID
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want just to insert new records into GameResult from the 2 other tables, try this

```
INSERT GameResult (GameId, FirstTeam, GoalsFT, GoalsST, SecondTeam)
SELECT G.GameId, T1.Name, G.GoalsFirstTeam, G.GoalsSecondTeam, T2.Name 
 FROM Games G INNER JOIN Teams T1 ON G.FirstTeamID=T1.ID
        INNER JOIN Teams T2 ON G.SecondTeamId=T2.ID
```

Comment: oh.. you wrote that you wanna update, i realized now that you just wanna insert new records, Right ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your table 'GameResult' hasn't got any records to update. Either fill it first and then use the abovementioned solution by Pupa Rebbe, or use a `Merge` statement to insert, update and (if needed) delete records.

For more information, see [this MS library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

> Delete From GameResult 
>   Go 
>   Insert GameResult (GameId,
>   FirstTeam,GoalsFT, GoalsST, SecondTeam) 
>   SELECT g.GameId,
>           t1.Name AS FirstTeam,
>           g.GoalsFirstTeam,         g.GoalsSecondTeam,
>           t2.Name AS SecondTeam 
>   FROM Game g 
>   INNER JOIN Team t1 ON g.FirstTeamId = t1.Id 
>   INNER JOIN Team t2 ON g.SecondTeamId = t2.Id